# Nginx Permissions Not Denied

Tags: nginx

I am having a problem with nginx permissions, I have done some research but none of the solutions I tried have been working.

Here is what I have tried including the errors as well.

I have installed nginx many times in the past so I am not sure why this is producing so many problems. Could it be the operating system?

```
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chmod +x /home/
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chown -R root:www-data /home/yessir/cache
chown: invalid group: `root:www-data'
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chown -R root:www-data /home/yessir/
chown: invalid group: `root:www-data'
[root@localhost ~]# chown -R root:nginx /home/yessir/
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chown -R root:nginx /home/yessir/cache
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chmod g+w -R /home/yessir/
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chmod g+w -R /home/yessir/cache
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# chmod g+w -R^C
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat /home/yessir/
  File: `/home/yessir/'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 45088770    Links: 4
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  498/   nginx)
Access: 2016-02-09 10:27:05.438388374 -0800
Modify: 2016-02-09 10:08:15.818386811 -0800
Change: 2016-02-09 10:27:05.438388374 -0800
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat /home/yessir/cahce
stat: cannot stat `/home/yessir/cahce': No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u nginx stat /home/yessir/cache
  File: `/home/yessir/cache'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 45088772    Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  498/   nginx)
Access: 2016-02-09 10:27:08.557388846 -0800
Modify: 2016-02-09 10:08:15.818386811 -0800
Change: 2016-02-09 10:27:08.557388846 -0800
[root@localhost ~]# service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] chown("/home/yessir/cache", 498) failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not indicated that permission is denied to /access/ the directory, the error message is indicating that permission is denied to /chown/ the directory.

This is strange because `chown` is usually only run as root, but Nginx usually runs as the `www-data` user.

When this error came up once before, the answer turned out to be the [target directory had been mounted remotely (or in a virtual machine?) and the mount settings weren't quite right](https://serverfault.com/questions/640198/nginx-operation-not-permitted). Be chance, is /home/yessir/cache hosted remotely or in a virtual machine?